# Texture or colour only on the displacement vector

Tags: displacement, texture-coordinates

i have this node setup acting as the displacement, what i would like to do is add a texture or a colour only where the displacement is being added on the object, i would like to make molten like cracks but i cant find the way to apply that colour only on the cracks[image]

[image: mesh and node setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add in a mix node, another principled shader and a color ramp.

[image]

Create a 2nd principled shader (this will be your lava).

Connect it with a mix shader, use a color ramp and have your displacement nodes connect to it.

Then on your color ramp adjust the flags to your liking.

Comment: oh this is gold, thanks a lot pal, i was trying to make a mix color of 2 textures and use the displace node setup as the fac input, that didnt work but this works like a charm <3